# facebook facepile tip

Tags: facebook-social-plugins

I need fast&easy tip.

I'm tempted to 'socialize my website' a little,so I gave a look to facebook facepile social plugin definition:

```
"[..] If the user does not have friends who have liked your page or have connected to your site, no faces will be shown.[..]"
```

I was wondering if "connected" meant just "browsing my website"?

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No connected means that they accepted to share their facebook data with you through your application by clicking on the "allow" button on the window promted by the FB-app

Comment: Thanks! It turns out all my testing(read: frustration) was because I wanted a <fb:like-box> instead of <fb:facepile> - go figure :)

Answer (score 1):

For facebook application you can do this.

```
<script>
  function fbLoginStatus(response) {
    if (response.status != 'unknown') {
     $('.facebook_facepile').show(); // show your facepile iframe 
    }
  }
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.getLoginStatus(fbLoginStatus);
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', fbLoginStatus);
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```